# Run a query for multiple entries from column in txt file and return the result in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a simple query like this :

```
SELECT
  chr_id AS chr_id,
  position AS position,
  ref_allele AS ref_allele,
  alt_allele AS alt_allele,
  rs_id AS rs_id,
  gene_id_any AS gene_id_any

FROM
  `open-targets-genetics.genetics.variants`
WHERE
  rs_id = 'rs182954137'
```

I would like to run in BigQuery the same query but for multiple rs_id imported from a table in txt (there is a column named rs_id). Should i upload the txt file and JOIN the two files of there is another way ?

I tried only the version with one entry like above

Comment: You can simply try `WHERE rs_id IN (SELECT rs_id FROM table_from_file1 UNION DISTINCT SELECT rs_id FROM table_from_file2)`.

Comment: table_from_file1 and table_from_file2 are my txt files loaded in bigquery ?

Comment: i have a txt file with different columns. I want to run the query for each element of the column rs_id. It includes 10000 rows with different rs_ids.

Comment: Yes, since you have all the records in a file, upload the file into a BigQuery table and do `WHERE rs_id IN (SELECT rs_id FROM table_from_file)` or `INNER JOIN table_from_file USING (rs_id)`